# Web scrapping request.get not giving back the HTML page as required

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to web scrapping , I was trying to scrape "https://opencorporates.com" , but while using request.get instead of getting the HTML content it returns a script which i guess is for generating a document cookie , which then loads the page. I am guessing that i need to wait for the page to load or something , or tap into the document cookie that its generating but i am not sure how to do that or if it is the right approach.(I cannot use Selenium)

**My Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


company_name = "RI DUDDING LIMITED"

# Prepare the search URL
search_url = "https://opencorporates.com/companies?q=" + company_name
# Send a GET request to the search URL
response = requests.get(search_url)

# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

# Find the company information section
company_section = soup.find('li', class_='search_result')

if company_section:
    # Extract the company page URL
    company_url = company_section.find('a')['href']

    # Send a GET request to the company page URL
    company_response = requests.get(company_url)
    company_soup = BeautifulSoup(company_response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Extract the desired information from the company page
    company_name = company_soup.find('h1', class_='company_name').text.strip()
    company_address = company_soup.find('span', itemprop='address').text.strip()
    company_status = company_soup.find('dd', class_='entity_status').text.strip()

    # Print the retrieved information
    print("Company Name:", company_name)
    print("Address:", company_address)
    print("Status:", company_status)
else:
    print("Company not found.")
```

**OUTPUT**
[o/p 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GXUI.png)
[o/p continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9x5.png)

REQUIRED Output is the HTML code that I can see when I inspect the page on chrome. Something like below :
[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yA56.png)

Comment: You can use a browser to get the cookie KEY from the header and pass it with your request.

Comment: Below answer should address that Anant.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineer the function which generate the `cookie`, Below code should address it. By the way you can apply same using `requests` / `bs4`.

> pip install trio httpx selectolax js2py

Please note I've done that over iPad where my environment configured with those libraries.

```py
import httpx
import trio
from selectolax.lexbor import LexborHTMLParser
import re
import js2py
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'
}


async def get_soup(content):
    return LexborHTMLParser(content)


async def get_company(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for client, url in channel:
            r = await client.get(url)
            soup = await get_soup(r.content)
            pp({
                'Name': soup.css_first('title').text(strip=True).split(':', 1)[0],
                'Address': soup.css_first('ul.address_lines').text(separator=', '),
                'Status': soup.css_first('dd.status').text(strip=True)
            })


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=headers, follow_redirects=True, base_url='https://opencorporates.com') as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        params = {
            "action": "search_companies",
            "commit": "Go",
            "controller": "searches",
            "jurisdiction_code": "",
            "order": "",
            "q": "RI DUDDING LIMITED",
            "utf8": "✓"
        }
        r = await client.get('/companies', params=params)
        match = re.search('(function le.*\");', r.text,
                          re.DOTALL).group(1).replace('{ document.cookie=', 'return ') + "};go()"
        cookies = js2py.eval_js(match)
        client.cookies.update({
            'KEY': cookies.split('=', 1)[1]
        })
        r = await client.get(r.url)
        soup = await get_soup(r.content)
        comanies = soup.css('a.company_search_result')
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(3):
                nurse.start_soon(get_company, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for co in comanies:
                    await sender.send([client, co.attrs['href']])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'R I DUDDING PROPERTIES LIMITED ',
 'Address': '64 Pembroke Road, Erith, DA8 1BZ, United Kingdom',
 'Status': 'Dissolved'}
```